# Odoo 15: Override JS function

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to override this Odoo JS function to remove the user notification, because it keeps appearing even there is no problem with the file, preview working fine. I used extend but it's not working, the debugger mode skipped var FieldBinaryImage

located in : addons/web/static/src/legacy/js/fields/basic_fields.js

```
/* global ace */
   odoo.define('web.basic_fields', function (require) {
   "use strict";

   /**
    * This module contains most of the basic (meaning: non relational) field
    * widgets. Field widgets are supposed to be used in views inheriting from
    * BasicView, so, they can work with the records obtained from a BasicModel.
    */

   var AbstractField = require('web.AbstractField');
   var config = require('web.config');
   var core = require('web.core');
   var datepicker = require('web.datepicker');
   var deprecatedFields = require('web.basic_fields.deprecated');
   var dom = require('web.dom');
   var Domain = require('web.Domain');
   var DomainSelector = require('web.DomainSelector');
   var DomainSelectorDialog = require('web.DomainSelectorDialog');
   var framework = require('web.framework');
   var py_utils = require('web.py_utils');
   var session = require('web.session');


    /**
    * I need to override the below function 
    */


 var FieldBinaryImage = AbstractFieldBinary.extend({
description: _lt("Image"),
fieldDependencies: _.extend({}, AbstractFieldBinary.prototype.fieldDependencies, {
    __last_update: {type: 'datetime'},
}),

template: 'FieldBinaryImage',
placeholder: "/web/static/img/placeholder.png",
events: _.extend({}, AbstractFieldBinary.prototype.events, {
    'click img': function () {
        if (this.mode === "readonly") {
            this.trigger_up('bounce_edit');
        }
    },
}),
supportedFieldTypes: ['binary'],
file_type_magic_word: {
    '/': 'jpg',
    'R': 'gif',
    'i': 'png',
    'P': 'svg+xml',
},
accepted_file_extensions: 'image/*',


/**
 * I need a just comment a line in this function 
 */



_render: function () {
    var self = this;
    var url = this.placeholder;
    if (this.value) {
        if (!utils.is_bin_size(this.value)) {
            // Use magic-word technique for detecting image type
            url = 'data:image/' + (this.file_type_magic_word[this.value[0]] || 'png') + ';base64,' + this.value;
        } else {
            var field = this.nodeOptions.preview_image || this.name;
            var unique = this.recordData.__last_update;
            url = this._getImageUrl(this.model, this.res_id, field, unique);
        }
    }
    var $img = $(qweb.render("FieldBinaryImage-img", {widget: this, url: url}));

    var width = this.nodeOptions.size ? this.nodeOptions.size[0] : this.attrs.width;
    var height = this.nodeOptions.size ? this.nodeOptions.size[1] : this.attrs.height;
    if (width) {
        $img.attr('width', width);
        $img.css('max-width', width + 'px');
        if (!height) {
            $img.css('height', 'auto');
            $img.css('max-height', '100%');
        }
    }
    if (height) {
        $img.attr('height', height);
        $img.css('max-height', height + 'px');
        if (!width) {
            $img.css('width', 'auto');
            $img.css('max-width', '100%');
        }
    }
    this.$('> img').remove();
    this.$el.prepend($img);

    $img.one('error', function () {
        $img.attr('src', self.placeholder);
        console.log('innnnnnnnn original ');




       // I want to comment the below line, I don't want to show error user notification



        self.displayNotification({ message: _t("Could not display the selected image"), type: 'danger' });
    });

    return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
},
```

I tried

```
odoo.define('dms.basic_fields', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    console.log('inside // done '); // showed in console

    var basic_fields = require('web.basic_fields');
    var core = require('web.core');
    var field_registry = require('web.field_registry');
    var FieldBinaryImage = basic_fields.FieldBinaryImage;
    var utils = require('web.utils');
    var qweb = core.qweb;
    var _t = core._t;
    var _lt = core._lt;

    // In debug mode, it does not even enter to FieldBinaryImageX when I used extend instead of include
    // Now I am using include but I get $img not defined and value not defined and many other errors



    var FieldBinaryImageX = FieldBinaryImage.include({
        // Override the _render method
        _render: function () {
            console.log('inside rener // Noooo :( '); // not showed in console means it did not reach here
            // called super
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            // same code I just commented the line
        var self = this;
        var url = this.placeholder;
        if (this.value) {
            if (!utils.is_bin_size(this.value)) {
                // Use magic-word technique for detecting image type
                url = 'data:image/' + (this.file_type_magic_word[this.value[0]] || 'png') + ';base64,' + this.value;
            } else {
                var field = this.nodeOptions.preview_image || this.name;
                var unique = this.recordData.__last_update;
                url = this._getImageUrl(this.model, this.res_id, field, unique);
            }
        }
        var $img = $(qweb.render("FieldBinaryImage-img", {widget: this, url: url}));
        // override css size attributes (could have been defined in css files)
        // if specified on the widget
        var width = this.nodeOptions.size ? this.nodeOptions.size[0] : this.attrs.width;
        var height = this.nodeOptions.size ? this.nodeOptions.size[1] : this.attrs.height;
        if (width) {
            $img.attr('width', width);
            $img.css('max-width', width + 'px');
            if (!height) {
                $img.css('height', 'auto');
                $img.css('max-height', '100%');
            }
        }
        if (height) {
            $img.attr('height', height);
            $img.css('max-height', height + 'px');
            if (!width) {
                $img.css('width', 'auto');
                $img.css('max-width', '100%');
            }
        }
        this.$('> img').remove();
        this.$el.prepend($img);

        $img.one('error', function () {
            $img.attr('src', self.placeholder);
            console.log('innnnnnnnn original ');
//            self.displayNotification({ message: _t("Could not display the selected image"), type: 'danger' });
        });

    },
    });

    // Register the custom widget
    field_registry.add('FieldBinaryImage', FieldBinaryImageX);

    return FieldBinaryImageX;
});
```

Please assist me and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if image files are corrupted

To create a js module, use the [Native Javascript Modules](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/reference/frontend/javascript_modules.html#native-javascript-modules) system:

> Most new Odoo javascript code should use the native javascript module system. This is simpler, and brings the benefits of a better developer experience with a better integration with the IDE.

To create a new image widget, extend the `FieldBinaryImage` as follows:

```js
/** @odoo-module */

import fieldRegistry from 'web.field_registry';
import basicFields from 'web.basic_fields';
import utils from 'web.utils';
import core from 'web.core';
var qweb = core.qweb;

var CustomFieldBinaryImage = basicFields.FieldBinaryImage.extend({
    _render: function () {
        
    },

});

fieldRegistry.add('custom_binary_image', CustomFieldBinaryImage);
```

To override the `_render` function, you can use `include` (Don't add to registry or return):

```js
basicFields.FieldBinaryImage.include({
    _render: function() {

    },
});
```

Comment: (Don't add to registry or return) 
Worked !! You're the BEST, thank you very much!